# How can I help my android phone find an mDNS device?

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, dns

I have a small WiFi gadget (based on an ESP8266), which is programmed to answer mDNS queries on `esp.local`. It can be discovered without any problems by iOS devices.

However, my phone's android (6.0.1) doesn't allow for this so I'm looking for ways to get this to work. The phone connects to my router's WiFi, so I think I can somehow go from there. I can install a local DNS to help resolve the address (there's an unused Raspberry Pi which could run `bind9`).

I also found [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49188/how-to-get-mdns-working-for-chrome-on-android) which has an answer that indicates that I can change android's preferred DNS to a local one, so this seems to be feasible. I'm not sure if the way of changing the phone's preferred DNS server described there really works, but doing that plus installing a custom local DNS server seems to be the only practical way.

Comment: Are you just doing normal name queries, or are you using it for DNS service discovery (aka rendezvous, Avahi)? Or to put it another way, what is the "working" behaviour in iOS that you're trying to replicate?

Comment: intended "working behavior" in iOS: open safari, type "esp.local" as url and get a web page (generated by the ESP8266) showing up